# how to make simple paging extjs4

Tags: extjs4.2

Good day everyone, I'm new user to Extjs 4. Right now, I have a problem in creating a simple paging (a test run just to familiarized on this). Please take a look at the example below.

```
  //creating a store data first
  var itemsPerPage = 2;
  var productivity = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',{ 
  fields : ['name','aht','numberOfCalls'],
  pageSize: itemsPerPage,
  autoLoad: true,
  data:{'items':[
    {name: 'Magelyn Cunanan', aht:'6:00', numberOfCalls:'50'},
    {name:'Martin Dejaresco', aht:'7:30', numberOfCalls:'40'},
    {name:'Emerson Dela Pena', aht:'8:00', numberOfCalls:'45'}
  ]},
   proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'pagingstore.js',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'items',
        totalProperty:'total'
    }
}

});

productivity.load({
  params:{
    start:0,
    limit: itemsPerPage
  }
});
```

then on my paging,

```
//... some code here. by the way this is a viewport container
    region: 'center',
    xtype: 'tabpanel',
    autoScroll: true,
    activeTab: 2,
    items: [{
        title: 'Agent\'s Productivity',  
        xtype: 'gridpanel',
        store: productivity,
        //for flex, indicates the amount of space this component will take up in its parent container. eg. if 1 this will take 100% of the container
        columns: [
          {text: 'Agent name',dataIndex: 'name', flex: 1}, 
          {text: 'Handling Time',dataIndex:'aht',flex:1},
          {text: 'Number of calls' ,dataIndex: 'numberOfCalls',flex:1}
        ],

        dockedItems:[{
          xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
          store: productivity,
          dock: 'bottom',
          displayInfo: true
         }],
```

all of these codes that I mentioned earlier are inside in `app.js`. The problem is when I run the program. The data that I stored doesn't appeared on the grid. It shows only no results plus 0 displays on the dockedItems.. I'm using this just to familiarize on how the extjs works and I need to use this extjs for my programming project in the future.

your answer and explanations to your answer is highly appreciated :)

thank you

Comment: You have set your url to pagingstore.js that doesn't look right, what is in that file?

Comment: thank you for the reply i forgot to mention that those i took are from the examples in the extjs http://www/extjs4/docs/index.html#!/api/Ext.toolbar.Paging. i'm trying to look at the google to find out the steps on how make the inline code in paging.. but i cant find an answer. Honestly I have no idea on what I'm my doing.. my bad :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For inline paging just need to code this

```
pageSize: itemsPerPage
proxy: {
type: 'memory',
enablePaging: true
}
```

oh boy.. I made myself difficult on this one :) but thanks for the reference

Answer (score 0):

What is apparent from your code:

1. you use inline `data` plus `ajax` proxy. These two are mutually exclusive - you either want some inline data or you want to pull data from a server via ajax.
2. proxy url points to a file (at least I guess it from the name `pagingstore.js`. This is not going to work as server side has to honor `start` and `limit` parameters, it has to return only matching recors and it has to return `total` number of records for paging to work.
3. you must never fiddle with `start` and `limit` yourself when loading the store. Store already knows what to do and sends these parameters automatically.

Comment: thank  you for the answer. honestly I don't have an idea on how to make this paging works. I just rely on this examples at the www/extjs4/docs/index.html#!/api/Ext.toolbar.Paging. Well there are descriptions and steps on how to create this but the descriptions on those functionalities seems diffcult to understand as a first time user.  I was just planning on how to make an inline data from the app.js.

Comment: It's questionable if you really need paging for inline data but if you really want that then follow this example: http://extjs.eu/ext-examples/#grid-memory-paging

Comment: cool.. thanks. just for a reference on how to conduct paging inline in the future. :) One last noob question (sorry) does this link also provides dynamic or or should I say external file? (incase for a external json i mean) I would be very happy to see your examples you wrote on the code and take it as a reference

Comment: Mr. Saki, thanks your tutorial worked out, I just found out a solution.. I just need to set up the proxy type from `ajax` to `memory` (since I'm using this as a inline) and `enablePaging` to `true` and setup the `pageSize` at the xtype portion.. That's the code that I'm looking for :)